# Can't understand why I keep getting segmentation fault for this code

Tags: c, linked-list

A very simple code:

```
typedef struct node {
    int x;
    struct node* next;
} *Node;

void advance_node(Node ptr) {
    ptr = ptr->next;
    while (ptr) {
        printf("%d\n", ptr->x);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    Node node1 = malloc(sizeof (*node1));
    Node node2 = malloc(sizeof (*node2));
    Node node3 = malloc(sizeof (*node3));

    node1->x = 1;
    node1->next = node2;

    node2->x = 4;
    node2->next = node3;

    node3->x = 9;
    node3->next = NULL;

    advance_node(node1);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect to see an output of 4 and 9, yet I keep getting a segmentation fault. Where is my mistake? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Also checking `while(ptr)` after reading `ptr` will lead to trouble for empty lists.

Comment: I assume the list is not empty.

Comment: I do not have compile error/warning even in `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra` nor problem at the execution but I do not like `Node node1 = malloc(sizeof (*node1));` and quite surprized this is allowed (node1 already exists ?), can you check doing `sizeof(struct node)` for all three ?

Comment: I **hate** these typedef hidding pointers ...

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://ideone.com/jfRhV9 - have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to see where the segfault occurs (and what values you have in your pointer at that time)?

Comment: _valgrind_ signals nothing

Comment: @bruno The `sizeof` operator doesn't care whether or not its parameter exists and it's not evaluated. It only cares if its type can be determined.

Comment: Are you getting the segmentation fault with this exact code? Can you at least use a debugger (or add logging) to figure out precisely where it segfaults?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I mean a non existing identifier cannot have a type ;-) So in fact `int a = a;` is like `int a; a = a;` if I can say, it is not intuitive _a_ exists before the ';' of its definition (if you understand what I try to say, I do not speak about initialization)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting a seg fault because of a `NULL` pointer.

You can easily protect against this in your `advance_node` function like so:

```
void advance_node(Node ptr) {
    if(!ptr) return; //protect against NULL pointer
    ptr = ptr->next;
    while (ptr) {
        printf("%d\n", ptr->x);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

I made this change and tested your code here: https://onlinegdb.com/B1endJr9E

Comment: Why should `node1` be null? And even if it is, the program would have crashed at `node1->x = 1;` so this solution doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your struct as

```
typedef struct node {
    int x;
    struct node* next;
} Node;
```

Then use `Node *node1 = malloc(sizeof (*node1));`